# Adding Custom Controls dll to Visual Studio ToolBox From Clearcase's Dynamic Views

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, clearcase

I have a custom control dll that I saved into my network drive.  I want to add it to Visual Studio toolbox, it came back and said Access is Denied.  If I placed it in my desktop then I don't have any problem.  Can you tell me what am I missing?

Update:  After further trials, the problems appear to be the files are in ClearCase's Dynamic View.  How to you get the toolbox to use dll from ClearCase's Dynamic View?

Answer (score 1):

A ClearCase dynamic view will not prevent read, only write access (if the file is not checked out, you can not open it for writing anything in it: you must checkout it first, provided your `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` references one the the groups of the Vob)

However, what usually happens is that dll is taken by a process, while that same dll copied elsewhere is free from any handle. (in that case, ClearCase would actually not be directly involved)

Try to find if any handle keep that dll to be used, using a tool like [Process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>).

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be to check your access rights against that network folder. Without more detail I coulnt say anyway I usually keep that kind of thing in the GAC as a toolbox item shouldnt really be moved around allot.